# Checking List returned from Rest to "null" in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rest

i am not able to check the status of list returned from REST whether the returned list is empty or not, data is returned in the following format `["IOC","Mycompany","Test"]`

```
 Test.save($scope.Data,
                   function(data){
                       //if(data==null) not working  
                       if(data[0]==null)//not working too
                           {
                           alert("empty")
                           }
                         });
```

How to check whether the returned list is empty or not???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, verify what you're actually getting when the list is empty.

You should check the length of an empty list rather than trying to index into it:

```
if ((data || []).length === 0) {
    // empty
}
```

Comment: im trying to send a List<String> that i got from a SpringJpa Query. And it gives the list as [null]. So when i send this to the angular, u have to check the first index right? Because here the list is not empty, the length shows as 1 in console

Comment: @DiliniPeiris Correct.  You could add a second if statement: `if (data.filter(x => x !== null).length === 0) { /* empty */ }`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the logic to check empty array to this-

```
if (data && data.length == 0) {
    alert("empty")
}
```

Comment: Should that be if(!data || data.length == 0)  ?

Comment: Sorry about that, @pramod-karandikar - didn't see your answer.

Comment: In javascript 0 (zero)  is false value. No need to check `data.length==0` only `data.length` is sufficient

Comment: If `data` is an empty array (`[]`), then `data.length` will return true since `data` will have `length` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides the function [angular#isObject](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isObject)

> Determines if a reference is an Object. Unlike `typeof` in JavaScript, `null`s are not considered to be objects. Note that JavaScript arrays are objects.

```
Test.save($scope.Data, function(data){
    if(!angular.isObject(data)){ 
       alert("empty")
    }
});
```